# Is there a function like ShellExecute in Java?

Tags: java

Im just looking for function that can run some .exe files
But I didn't find that function in Java
ShellExecute(Operation, File, Parameters, Directory, ShowCmd : String) is there a function like that?

Comment: Regarding the previous close: ShellExecute is not the same as `Runtime.exec`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction so there are not functions like that?

Comment: Besides how can I count the answer as right?I'm using mobile version

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`java.awt.Desktop`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html) provides some of that functionality:

- [`browse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) can be used to open the default browser for a specific URI
- [`open`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) opens a file for viewing (with the default viewer of the OS)
- [`edit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#edit(java.io.File)) opens a file for editing (with the default editor of the OS)
- ...

If you want to run arbitrary exe files, however, then [`Runtime.exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) is the way to go (but using it can be tricky, as you need to consume all streams for it to not lock up).

Comment: Yep but anyway I find out these function useful so thanks for the  answer